# Store a list of another model in a model in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a User model which should hold a list of a Message model.
This list (in Usesr model) should contain 20 Message objects which will be updated every 24 hours.
How can I implement this architecture in my model classes?

I'm thining about 2 solutions,
First to store a list attribute in User model:

```
class User (db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)

    def __init__ (self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.tempList = []

    def appendTempList (self, item):
        self.tempList.append (item)

    def removeTempListItems (self):
        self.tempList = []

class Message:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    context =  db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)

    def __init__(self,msg):
        self.context = msg

#some codes to add 20 random items into tempList of each User, every 24 hours
```

Is this a good approach? 
Can I store a list inside a model class as an attribute?!

My second approach is to use a many-to-many relation between these models:

```
user_message_table = db.Table ('user_message_table',
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('message_model.id')),
db.Column('message_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_model.id'))
)

class User (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_model'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    tempList = db.relationship("Message", secondary = user_message_table)

    def __init__ (self,name):
        self.name = name

    def appendTempList (self, item):
        self.tempList.append (item)
        db.session.commit()

    def removeTempListItems (self):
        self.tempList.remove()
        #remove item from user_message_table too

class Message:
    __tablename__ = 'message_model'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    context =  db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)

    def __init__(self,msg):
        self.context = msg
```

Any idea ?